# Changing the sign bit of a register in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, x86-16

I'm trying to write assembly code that does a fairly simple thing, it changes the sign bit (just the sign bit) of the register AL.

I need to find two different ways to do this, but sadly the solutions I came up with don't seem to be working.

1) I tried subtracting AL from itself twice:

```
mov BL,AL
sub AL,BL
sub AL,BL
```

But this changes more than just the sign bit. And I understand why.

2) I also tried adding 10000000 to AL. This indeed solves the problem, but if the sign bit of AL is 1, then I get an overflow and carry.

Is there a way to change just the sign bit, without running into overflow / carry problems?

Comment: just to clarify, do you just want to change just the sign bit, or change the number to a negative (as you may be using two complement)?

Comment: Just the sign bit. not 2s complement. thats why suggestion number (1) does not work. I just want to change the sign bit. All other bits must remain the same.

Comment: have you tried masking? So a combination of logic operations to preserve all the bits bar the sign, I need to give it a think.

Comment: What do you mean by overflow and carry, you need to preserve the flags? Otherwise can't you just or by 0x80?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "or by 0x80". And regarding masking - not matter what combination i think of, it seems to change other bits as well. And yes, I'd rather perserve the flags as they were.

Comment: yah so i think an xor on 0x80 would work

Comment: binary string 1000 0000(depends how big the representation is but all 0's after the first 1 )

Comment: Why does getting an overflow/carry matter? The results of `X ^ 0x80` and `X + 0x80` and also `X - 0x80` are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR operation the constant 0x8000 (for 16bit) with the register you want to change.

Bit of googling:

```
xor Bitwise logical XOR
  Syntax:   xor dest, src
  dest: register or memory
  src: register, memory, or immediate
  Action: dest = dest ^ src
  Flags Affected: OF=0, SF, ZF, AF=?, PF, CF=0
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know ASM so can't help with the implementation :s

Answer (score 3):

How about just doing:

```
XOR AL, 80H
```

?

also:

```
MOV BL, AL
MOV AL, 0
SUB AL, BL
AND BL, 7FH
AND AL, BL
```

Another thing to preserve the flags you can always go

```
   PUSHF
       // whatever
    POPF
```

Comment: doesn't change the sign if both are 0x80, 0x80, need XOR

Comment: @SamPalmer what do you mean? the subtraction? of course it will im negating al then restoring all the bits except the MSB

Comment: don't worry now, originally you wrote just OR not XOR :)

Answer (score 1):

Shift it into the carry flag, complement the flag and shift it back:

```
shl al, 1
cmc
rcr al, 1
```

To preserve the flags you can use `pushf` and `popf`.

Answer (score 0):

To change sign use NEG instruction

for example

```
MOV AX,0101        - AX = 0101
NEG AX             - AX = 1010
                      because of the NEG instruction


NEG instruction affects these flags only:
    CF, ZF, SF, OF, PF, AF.

NEG - Make operand negative (two's complement).
      Actually it reverses each bit of operand and then adds 1 to
      it. For example 5 will become -5, and -2 will become 2.
```

Comment: The OP is actually asking how to just flip the sign **bit**, which is not the same thing as getting the 2's complement negation of the whole integer.  This is why subtracting the original value twice didn't do what he wanted.  (Although it is obviously a much better choice than the 3 instructions he used for that experiment.)